# Wininet InternetSetStatusCallback not working

Tags: delphi, winapi, ftp, wininet

I'm trying to detect when an ftp server closes the connection I opened in my application. I'm using the WinInet functionality.

I found some examples that make use of the `InternetSetStatusCallback` function. I implemented a callback function `StatusCallback` and passed it's address in the call to `InternetSetStatusCallback`. `InternetSetStatusCallback` gives me back a status of type `PFNInternetStatusCallback`. The status is not `INTERNET_INVALID_STATUS_CALLBACK`, meaning that my function `StatusCallback` was accepted as a callback function, but the callback function is never called. I tried to trigger it by having the server timeout the connection and by manually taking the server down.

My Delphi code is below. Could anybody please help me out here? Or would this be in improper way of detecting the connection status?

Thank you

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ExtCtrls, StdCtrls,
  WinInet,
  Winsock;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    lblConnected:   TLabel;
    Label2:         TLabel;
    tmrNOOP:        TTimer;
    btnConnect:     TButton;
    btnDisconnect:  TButton;
    Memo1:          TMemo;
    procedure btnConnectClick( Sender: TObject );
    procedure btnDisconnectClick( Sender: TObject );
    procedure SendNOOP( Sender: TObject );
  private
    FFtpRootHandle:     HINTERNET;
    FFtpSessionHandle:  HINTERNET;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{
  N.b. we DO need to define FtpCommand here as it has been defined incorrectly
  in WinInet.pas (missing last parameter)
}
function FtpCommand(
  hConnect:         HINTERNET;
  fExpectResponse:  BOOL;
  dwFlags:          DWORD;
  lpszCommand:      PChar;
  dwContext:        DWORD;
  out FtpCmd:       HINTERNET ): BOOL; stdcall; external 'wininet.dll' name 'FtpCommandA';

procedure StatusCallback(
  hInet:        HINTERNET;
  Context:      DWORD_PTR;
  Status:       DWORD;
  pInformation: Pointer;
  InfoLength:   DWORD ); stdcall;
var
  s: string;
begin
  case Status of
    INTERNET_STATUS_CLOSING_CONNECTION: s := 'Closing the connection to the server';
    INTERNET_STATUS_CONNECTED_TO_SERVER: s := 'Successfully connected to the socket address: ';
    INTERNET_STATUS_CONNECTING_TO_SERVER: s := 'Connecting to the socket address';
    INTERNET_STATUS_CONNECTION_CLOSED: s := 'Successfully closed the connection to the server';
    INTERNET_STATUS_CTL_RESPONSE_RECEIVED: s := 'Not implemented';
    INTERNET_STATUS_HANDLE_CLOSING: s := 'This handle value has been terminated';
    INTERNET_STATUS_HANDLE_CREATED: s := 'InternetConnect has created the new handle';
    INTERNET_STATUS_INTERMEDIATE_RESPONSE: s :=
      'Received an intermediate (100 level) status code message from the server';
    INTERNET_STATUS_NAME_RESOLVED: s := 'Successfully found the IP address: ' + PChar(pInformation);
    INTERNET_STATUS_PREFETCH: s := 'Not implemented';
    INTERNET_STATUS_RECEIVING_RESPONSE: s := 'Waiting for the server to respond to a request ';
    INTERNET_STATUS_REDIRECT: s := 'HTTP request is about to automatically redirect the request ' +
      PChar(pInformation);
    INTERNET_STATUS_REQUEST_COMPLETE: s := 'An asynchronous operation has been completed';
    INTERNET_STATUS_REQUEST_SENT: s := 'Successfully sent the information request to the server: ' +
      IntToStr(Integer(pInformation)) + ' Byte';
    INTERNET_STATUS_RESOLVING_NAME: s := 'Looking up the IP address: ' + PChar(pInformation);
    INTERNET_STATUS_RESPONSE_RECEIVED: s := 'Successfully received a response from the server: ' +
      IntToStr(Integer(pInformation)) + ' Byte';
    INTERNET_STATUS_SENDING_REQUEST: s := 'Sending the information request to the server.';
    INTERNET_STATUS_STATE_CHANGE:
      begin
        s := 'Moved between a secure (HTTPS) and a nonsecure (HTTP) site.';
        case DWORD(pInformation) of
          INTERNET_STATE_CONNECTED: s := s + #13#10 + 'Connected state. Mutually exclusive with disconnected state.';
          INTERNET_STATE_DISCONNECTED: s := s + #13#10 +
            'Disconnected state. No network connection could be established.';
          INTERNET_STATE_DISCONNECTED_BY_USER: s := s + #13#10 + 'Disconnected by user request.';
          INTERNET_STATE_IDLE: s := s + #13#10 + 'No network requests are being made by Windows Internet.';
          INTERNET_STATE_BUSY: s := s + #13#10 + 'Network requests are being made by Windows Internet.';
        end;
      end;
  end;
  Writeln(s);
end;

procedure TForm1.btnConnectClick( Sender: TObject );
var
  flags:  Cardinal;
  Status: PFNInternetStatusCallback;
  I:      Integer;
begin
  FFtpRootHandle :=
    InternetOpen(
      Pchar( 'NOOP TESTER'),
      INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT,
      nil,
      nil,
      0 );

  if not Assigned( FFtpRootHandle ) then
  begin
    RaiseLastOSError();
    Exit;
  end;

  flags := INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE or INTERNET_FLAG_NO_UI;
  FFtpSessionHandle :=
    InternetConnect(
      FFtpRootHandle,
      PAnsiChar( '127.0.0.1' ),
      Word( 21 ),
      PAnsiChar( 'x11' ),
      PAnsiChar( 'x11' ),
      INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP,
      Flags,
      INTERNET_FLAG_ASYNC );

  Status := InternetSetStatusCallback( FFtpSessionHandle,       INTERNET_STATUS_CALLBACK(@StatusCallback) );
if NativeInt( Status ) = INTERNET_INVALID_STATUS_CALLBACK then
  raise Exception.Create( 'Callback function is not valid' );

if not Assigned( FFtpSessionHandle ) then
begin
    InternetCloseHandle( FFtpRootHandle );
    RaiseLastOSError();
    Exit;
  end;
  lblConnected.Color := clGreen;
  btnConnect.Enabled := false;
  tmrNOOP.Interval := 10000;
  tmrNOOP.Enabled := true;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnDisconnectClick( Sender: TObject );
begin
  tmrNOOP.Enabled := false;
  if Assigned( FFtpSessionHandle ) then
  begin
    InternetCloseHandle( FFtpSessionHandle );
    if Assigned( FFtpRootHandle ) then
    begin
      InternetCloseHandle( FFtpRootHandle );
    end;
  end;
  lblConnected.Color := clRed;
  btnConnect.Enabled := true;
end;

procedure TForm1.SendNOOP( Sender: TObject );
var
  NOOPSuccess:  Boolean;
  FtpCmd:       HINTERNET;
begin
  NOOPSuccess :=
    FtpCommand(
      FFtpSessionHandle,
      false,
      FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY,
      PAnsiChar( 'noop' ),
      0,
      FtpCmd );
  if NOOPSuccess then
  begin

  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Have you tried `InternetSetStatusCallback( FFtpSessionHandle,` (after the InternetConnect)?

Comment: Yes, I have, but it made no difference

Answer (score 0):

[Read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385120.aspx):

> The callback function specified in the lpfnInternetCallback
>   parameter will not be called on ... the connection handle when
>   the dwContext handle of InternetConnect is set to zero
>   (INTERNET_NO_CALLBACK).

You are indeed setting the `dwContext` parameter of `InternetConnect()` to zero.

Comment: I managed to have the callback function called upon sending the NOOP, but NOT when the server disconnects me, which is what I'm after.